# How use curses.raw() and curses.cbreak()

Tags: python, keyboard, curses

So first I want to capture the keys (w,a,s,d) when are pressed.
And I think with curses I can make it, but I am new using python, and I need help, How capture the key pressed in the keyboard. I try with a input but I need touch enter to change, but in my program I don't need pressing enter. I just need when I press, for example w do something without pressing enter.

Comment: You need to make your question a bit more clear & also, show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

`window.getch()` is what you're looking for.
It may help to browse through the documentation, as all these basic things are clearly stated there:

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch